# Probleme to Extract data fees from web site

Tags: html, excel, vba

I encounter a problem when I try to click the button usin VBA/HTML.
When i input data in the textbox , i will click enter or on the button "Searche" but the click button doesn't works. Please help  Many thanks

Web site is : https://sellercentral.amazon.fr/fba/profitabilitycalculator/index?lang=en_GB

My VBA code :

```
Set IEDoc = IE.document
Set DOCelement = IEDoc.getElementById("search-string")
DOCelement.Value = "5010993370528"

Set DOCelement = IEDoc.getElementById("a-autoid-1")
DOCelement.submit
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQKnE.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XEuW.png)

Comment: The element "a-autoid-1" is a Submit Button. You can "Submit" a "Form"

Comment: Thanks Tanmay but it still doensn't works. This code sames works but the page doesn't charge. I put this :

Set IEDoc = IE.document
Set DOCelement = IEDoc.getElementById("search-string")
DOCelement.Value = "5010993370528"

Set DOCelement = IEDoc.getElementById("search-form")
DOCelement.submit
I guess that there is a hidden area. Thanks for your assitance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code is Tried and tested in IE11

```
Sub amazon()
    On Error GoTo Errors
        Dim ie As Object
        Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        ie.navigate "https://sellercentral.amazon.fr/fba/profitabilitycalculator/index?lang=en_GB"
        ie.Visible = True
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:05 AM#

        Set IEDoc = ie.document
        Set DOCelement = IEDoc.getElementById("search-string")
        DOCelement.Focus
        DOCelement.Click
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:01 AM#
        DOCelement.Value = "5010993370528"

        Set DOCelement = IEDoc.getElementById("a-autoid-1").getelementsbytagname("input")(0)
        DOCelement.Click
        Application.Wait Now + #12:00:05 AM#
Errors:
        MsgBox Err.Description
End Sub
```

The Focus and click is needed otherwise the text is grayed-out

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Tanmay but it still doensn't works. 
This code sames works but the page doesn't charge.
I put this :

```
Set IEDoc = IE.document
Set DOCelement = IEDoc.getElementById("search-string")
DOCelement.Value = "5010993370528"

Set DOCelement = IEDoc.getElementById("search-form")
DOCelement.submit
```

I guess that there is a hidden area.
Thanks for your assitance